# phpunit : test api and mock some method in same controller, but mocked method is not work

Tags: laravel, phpunit

controller code

```
class testController extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controller
{
    public function test1() {
        $a = $this->test2();
        ...
    }

    protected function test2() {
        return '123';
    }
}
```

unit test code

```
class Test extends TestCase
{
    public function unittest()
    {
        $mockController = \Mockery::mock('App\Http\Controllers\testController')->makePartial()->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
        $mockController ->shouldReceive('test2')->andReturn('456');

        $response = $this->json('GET', action('testController@test1'));

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

when do unit test, test2 method always return 123, not 456
Anything help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `$this->json()` does internally (it's not a part of plain PHPUnit), but anyway, the problem is probably that you don't inject your  `$mockController` anywhere, and thus the original controller is requested by unit test.